# Wordpress - How to have a duplicate text editor in a specific custom post?

Tags: wordpress, text-editor

I am working on a multilingual app with Wordpress and the purpose of this for me is to be able to type another language version of the post content say french version of it in an alternative text editor below the default one and the text of it be saved as a meta data[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add meta box to the custom post type as below for registering custom text editor.

```
<?php

function register_text_editor_2() {
    add_meta_box("text_editor-2", "Text Editor 2", "print_text_editor_2",
    "products", "normal", "high");    
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'register_text_editor_2');

?>
```

`where text_editor-2` is the ID that the meta box's ID, Text Editor 2 is the meta box's title, `print_text_editor_2` is the function to print out the HTML for the meta box, `products` is the custom post type, `normal` is the location of the meta box, and `high` specifies that it should be shown as high in the page as possible(usually below the default tinyMCE editor).

You should add `print_text_editor_2` function to print custom text editor as bewlow.

```
<?php

function print_text_editor_2() {
    echo <<<EOT
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery("#tinymce").addClass("mceEditor");
            if ( typeof( tinyMCE ) == "object" &&
                 typeof( tinyMCE.execCommand ) == "function" ) {
                tinyMCE.execCommand("mceAddControl", false, "tinymce");
            }
        });
    </script>
    <textarea id="tinymce" name="tinymce"></textarea>
EOT;
}

?>
```

Comment: Hi Timberland, Glad that it helped...:-)